# WebRTC / getUserMedia alternatives for mobile devices

Tags: audio, webrtc, mobile-website, voice-recognition, getusermedia

I am trying to run a hand-clapping voice recognition JS code on mobile devices. The code uses [`getUserMedia`](https://gist.github.com/pachacamac/d7b3d667ecaa0cd39f36) in order to record the audio and works pretty well in desktop computers.

However, `getUserMedia` does not seem to be fully supported in mobile browsers ([mobilehtml5.org](http://mobilehtml5.org/), [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream)). For instance, Apple devices block this call even from the Chrome browsers.

**Are there any widely-supported alternative for `getUserMedia` for recording audio on mobile devices?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use **HTML Media Capture** which, with the exception of capturing audio only on iOS, is widely supported since iOS 6 and Android 2.

Correct Syntax: https://blog.addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/

Demo: https://addpipe.com/html-media-capture-demo/